# Валидация формы JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validate

Хотел бы получить ваше мнение по моему коду.

У меня есть форма, там одно поле `email`. Я делаю проверку этого поля. Так же хочу, что бы при отправки формы, поле очищалось, и может выводить `alert`, что форма была отправлена. Так же я как отменил действие `submit`, но сделал его ужасно, мне кажется надо по-иному это делать.

Прилагаю код. Так же я пробовал сделать, чтобы когда форма пустая она не отправлялась. Буду благодарен за комментарии. Всем добра.

А ещё бы хотел узнать. Хорошим тоном считается в Js, когда сначала идут переменные, функции и вызовы функций?

```
form.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
})

// Validate email
function validateEmail(value) {
  return emailRegexp.test(value)
}

function updateInput() {
  if (validateEmail(email.value) || email.value === "") {
    email.style.border = "2px solid green"
    formBtn.disabled = false
  } else {
    email.style.border = "2px solid red"
    email.style.borderColor = 'red';
    formBtn.disabled = true
  }
}

email.addEventListener("input", updateInput)
```

Comment: В приниципе нормально. Но отмену сабмита формы надо делать в событии `submit` а не `click`.

Answer (score 0):

На форму вешайте не click, а submit. И там делайте проверку на правильность введенных данных в инпуте